# Error after installing the Ubuntu

Tags: boot, 22.04, usb-installation

I installed Ubuntu in my HP pavilion 14.I can able to use it only with the help of my pendrive.when i eject it,Ubuntu not shown in the screen.
Also it shows while launching "no irq handler from the vector"

Solve these problems team.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and what specific version or type did you download and install, i.e., did you download the desktop version, mini.iso, or server, etc.

Comment: I'm installed v22.04.3 LTS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.